# AAD-Authentication not working since Visual Studio 2017 update to version 15.7.4

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-active-directory

I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.7.4 installed on Windows 10. The OS is connected to my AAD Work/School account. My problem occurs on 5 different machines and started to appear today.

When I start VS I'm logged in (top right) and every thing is fine. The list of subscriptions is shown in Cloud Explorer too.

I now open a ASP.NET Core web project and want to publish it to an existing Web App in Azure. As soon as I'm in the screen where I can define the target subscription, VS starts to re-authenticate eventually showing the popup-dialog querying for my credentials. This dialog sometime appears several times in a row.

I can authenticate without any error shown and now everywhere in VS (Account settings, Cloud Explorer, Server Explorer, Publish Dialog) appears the "Reenter your credentials" link and all subscriptions are inaccessible now.

From this moment on there is now way to authenticate against AAD inside of VS without getting the "Reenter-thing" anymore.

What I already tried:

- Went to account settings and removed all existing accounts from VS -> restarted VS and performed signup again.
- Closed all VS instances -> deleted the file system folder `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService` -> started VS and signed in again
- Right click on Azure Node in Server Explorer and selected "Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription..."

Nothing of the above works. I was able to use this stuff just 2 days ago. That's why I suspect the update.

I then tried to post a question on [Visual Studio Community Site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com). This asks me to use the "Report a problem"-feature in VS. Guess what? The sign-in is broken there too so I cannot even get my problem to MS.

Any further suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: We went on with some further tests and found the same issues with two more users on multiple machines. Strangely, one user (that's me) in the same AAD and on the same devices doesn't have the problem and can authenticate and publish as usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried out to use a none Windows User - create a blank User on your Subscription and deploy with this user...

Maybe a problem with windows integrated User?

Best
Niels

Today it was just announced that there is a new feature in preview in AzureAD - maybe that’s the reason? 
See 
https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2018/06/19/azure-ad-password-protection-and-smart-lockout-are-now-in-public-preview/

**Update**

Maybe just refresh the User Tokens...

Use this PS lines…

```ps1
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred 
$user = Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -eq "your_aad_login_name"}
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId $user.ObjectId
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint, Niels. I could publish with a fresh user without any problem. I now switched to a local user in my Windows, linked this to AAD again and signed into VS without any problems. So token refresh seems to be broken currently.

Comment: As I wrothe the comment, the login using an user which is connected to Windows 10 again fails. The solution posted by @Niels works but there still is an issue with Windows-10-connected AAD accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried it out and it actually worked. After I restarted my computer it now has the same behavior as I described. So we now know that this is something about local token cache on Windows, right?

Comment: One of the affected users tried running the provided powershell scripts and it didn't work for him, regardless of rebooting. The problem seems to be on a bigger scope than just a local token cache.